# If I load a background image using Image(), will it be cached?

Tags: javascript, caching, background, load, preload

I have two pages and after the first page loads, I use javascript image object like this:

```
var workshopBack = new Image();
workshopBack.src = "/images/wBack.jpg";
```

The wBack.jpg is the background for the next page, but it is huge, so I load it before in the first page itself. Now my question, when the user navigates to the next page, will the background be loaded from cache or will it be downloaded it again?

Comment: just try it!, check using the firebug in firefox which will tell whether it was served from broswer cache or from source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally loading an image will keep it in the cache for a while, but there are no guarantees.

There is no standard for how the browser cache should work, it's just implemented as best the browser vendor knows. It's entirely possible that some browsers have an implementation that will drop the image as soon as possible, because of its size. You just have to test in different browsers to see how they react.

Also, the state of the cache may also affect the result. Even if your browser keeps the image, some other user may have a different set of files in the cache, or a different cache limitation, that makes the browser drop the image. You can only make sure that it works in most cases, there is never a guarantee that it will work in all cases.

Comment: Well if that's the case, is it ok to load the entire page using Ajax and then set the manifest file so that cache is guaranteed?

Comment: @Inglocines: That could help. but it's still not guaranteed. Some browswers (e.g. Firefox) requires the user to accept a notification before anything is stored locally). Some browsers (e.g. IE9 and earlier) doesn't support manifests.